# Prevent page scrolling on input focus (mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a little Spanish translation game.

The input is high enough on the page that the default scrolling doesn't need to occur when the onscreen keyboard pops up. And it cuts off critical info at the top (see image).

I'd like for there to be no movement on the page when the user focuses on the input.

I tried this JS and it didn't work:

```
const GUESS_INPUT = document.getElementById("guess-input");

GUESS_INPUT.focus({
preventScroll: true,});
```

[image: Image of my problem]

Comment: we cannot do much without the actual code.

Comment: overflow:hidden on the document body should do